# Bidirectional data transfer- serial to Eth (Socat) (RPi)

Tags: tcp, raspberry-pi3, uart, socat, mavlink

I appear stuck and am calling for help!

I have a RPi3 B+ model connected via GPIO pins 14/15 (/dev/ttyS0) to Pixhawk using the Mavlink Comm protocol working!
Code: Select all

`$ sudo -s`

`$ mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyS0 --baudrate 57600`

can add also options like:
Code: Select all

`--out=udp:(IP):Port`

multiple times to how ever many IPs i want.

Now is the tricky part, to my RPi i have an Eth connection connected to an RX/TX device. [Device IP: 192.168.19.240 ; Device Port:23]
I want to transfer all of the incoming data to/from the RX/TX device to the Pixhawk and back.

Ive tried using Socat with multiple commands such as:

`$sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 udp4:192.168.19.240:23`

with no success.

Any information is valuable!!

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

The TX/RX device, connected to the RPi, was also transmitting (via RF) to a Ground Control station with the same identical Device. The only difference one was defined as airborne (the one with the pi) and the second was ground.

I tried accessing the airborne TX/RX via socat, but a simple ping "ip of the PC connected to ground TX/RX" showed connectivity between the pi and the PC on the ground.

A simple command to initiated mavproxy and define PC as master on the RPi:

`mavproxy.py --master=udp:PC IP ADDRESS:14550`

and everything works.